# Explanation and proof of distance and correlation expression found in ebook

Tags: correlation, mathematical-statistics, bivariate, distance-covariance

I am reading 'Data Analysis for the Life Sciences' and came across a small section touching upon what I believe relates to distance correlation. I am new to this concept and would like some help understanding it. I don't know how the author arrived to the 3rd and 4th equation from the 2nd equation. I tried multiplying out the squared term in the 2nd equation, however it did not result in the 3rd equation. Can someone shed some light; here are the relevant pages from the ebook. Thanks in advance.

---

[image: photo1]

[image: photo2]